# Azure table does not exist error when running Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am receiving this error when connecting my Table Storage when running my Azure function app. I have a Table Storage DB in Azure and also trying to run it through the emulator

[image]

DIConfig.cs to register services & prepare the TableServiceClient

```
using Azure.Data.Tables;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Template.Infrastructure;

public static class DIConfig
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var tableClientConnectionString = configuration["AzureFunctionsJobHost:connectionStrings:tableStorage"];

        services.AddScoped(_ => new TableServiceClient(tableClientConnectionString));
        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(TableClientRepository<>));

        return services;
    }
}
```

**Host.JSON**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "connectionStrings": {
    "tableStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the exception `The table specified does not exist.` - it means that emulator working just fine, but Azure table doesn't exist.

You can just add in your code (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data.tables-readme-pre#create-an-azure-table) following code, which ensures that table exists.

```
string tableName = "YourTableName";
TableItem table = serviceClient.CreateTableIfNotExists(tableName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have the Azure table inside the emulator and also on my Azure portal as well. Would you know where to place the above check?

Comment: Well if you are sure you have table in both places, maybe there is some misspell in name. You should put above check before first use of table - so when you are using table you have certainty that table exists.

Comment: @Deryn I have the same issue, azure table exist but querying it in iOS swift says it doesn't exist, did you solve the issue yet?